# TortoiseSVN Missing Checkout from Context Menu

Tags: windows-7, tortoisesvn, windows-7-x64

I am running Windows 7 64 bit with TortoiseSVN 1.6.16 - 64 bit edition.  The only issue with Tortoise is that Checkout is missing from the main context menu and the Tortoise SVN submenu.

I have access to all other Tortoise functions just fine.  The settings indicate that Checkout should be there.

Steps I have tried already:

1. Uninstalling and reinstalling
2. Reinstalling twice
3. Install once, repair install the second time
4. Restarted after every install, repair, and uninstall
5. Verified that I have a 64 bit client

Comment: I have a [screenshot here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yLmaw.png), but not enough reputation to post as part of the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Checkout only appears on non-svn folders (ie with no .svn hidden folders inside).
Try on an empty folder.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that "Command line tools" was deselected during installation. Make sure it's installed too.

And i also had to reboot the pc for it to show up.